# Selenium web scraping elements from tag

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm looping from a diferents urls trying to get some information from some movies

I'm trying to get the writers. I am not extracting each csselector because perhaps in some other movie there is not the same number of scriptwriters and it would give an error. For this reason I want to extract the elements that are bound to the tag. For example I want to get all the elements of the tag "a" (image attached)

I have the following code but it's not working:

`driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"a")`

I don't know if there is any other way without using tag

url movie = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7740496/?ref_=watch_fanfav_tt_t_4"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using python. Try to use one of this methods:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//span[contains(text(),"Guión")])[1]/../div//a')
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'(//span[contains(text(),"Guión")])[1]/../div//a')
```

Check selenium documentation: [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

My result with java code it returns 3 elements as you want.

[image]

Comment: It gives me all the paths with this tag. I need as a input only the 3 names of scripwriters (Guillermo del Toro, Kim Morgan, William Lindsay Gresham)

Comment: ok changed xpath selector for this: "(//span[contains(text(),"Guión")])[1]/../div//a" it will return you 3 elements.

Comment: It returns to me '[ ]' without nothing inside

Comment: In selenium you are using english or spanish language? If it is english you must put Writers y not Guión. Or change your browser language.